# C# MVC to IIS windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008

I currently have a publish project from my local IIS which is windows 8 and already working but, my problem is I need to transfer it to our VM which is windows server 2008. I need some guidance or recommendation if I need to install Visual studio as well on the VM to publish it or is there any easy way that can simply copy the publish file from my local to VM windows server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish from your project from local machine visual studio to remote server(in your case VM) if you have access to that server.

Alternatively manually publishing web project is just compiling in release mode with all dependencies & putting code in some IIS site/virtual directory with required Application pool settings.

Microsoft has very comprehensive documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/